# Android Expandable List view does not fill the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am using expandable list view to create some kinds of nested lists; it's on a view with a list and submit button .

However, the list never fills the screen and it only fills a small part of the view.

In the code example below, I used the scroll view to have the submit button appear. Before using the scroll view, the submit button never showed and the list then fill all the screen:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/blue_overlay_2x"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/contain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/actionbar"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/tripReview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:paddingLeft="5dp"
     android:paddingRight="5dp">

     <ExpandableListView
         android:id="@+id/feed_list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
         android:gravity="top"
         android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
         android:numColumns="1"
         android:groupIndicator="@null"
         android:padding="0dip"
         android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
         android:smoothScrollbar="true"

         android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

         android:transcriptMode="normal" />
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/submit_button"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:background="@drawable/bg_button_color_theme"
             android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
             android:padding="@dimen/space_2_3x"
             android:text="@string/submit_support"
             android:textAllCaps="true"
             android:textColor="@color/pure_white"
             android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
 </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>  
    <include layout="@layout/load_more_progress_bar_layout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I get the expandable list view to fill the screen?

Comment: If you want your progress bar to be on top of the other layout, I'd use a FrameLayout for the top Layout, not a RelativeLayout.

Comment: the progress bar apears ok , the issue is with the list which its hight never increase after the data filling , altought its highet is wrap_content

Comment: did you trying changing `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for your ExpandableListView?